# Google play services achievement loading via Pending result

Tags: android, google-play-services, achievements

What i'm doing here is loading all achievements and saving them to a local Map:

This is my code

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean> getAchievements(){
    final LinkedHashMap<String,Boolean> achievementMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
    PendingResult<Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult> achievementsResult = Games.Achievements.load(gameHelper.getApiClient(), false);
    achievementsResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult loadAchievementsResult) {
            if(loadAchievementsResult != null) {
                if (loadAchievementsResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                    if (loadAchievementsResult.getAchievements() != null) {
                        AchievementBuffer achievementBuffer = loadAchievementsResult.getAchievements();
                        for(Achievement achievement : achievementBuffer){
                            achievementMap.put(achievement.getName(),achievement.getState() == Achievement.STATE_UNLOCKED);
                        }
                        achievementBuffer.close();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
    return achievementMap;
}
```

Everything is working fine, even tho i was pretty sure its NOT working with the returned HashMap beeing empty. As i understand it, im just creating an empty hashmap, setting a "listener" and returning the empty hashmap. I thought the callback is called when the data is ready at some point in the future, but as its working now, i have the data in the hashmap before i return from this method, even tho i dont wait for it or anything. Dont get me wrong, i'm happy its working that easy, but i think i cant be sure the data is already written to the hasmap when i return, and thus get into trouble with maybe a slower network connection.

Am i right and can anyone tell me, why the callback is called before i return from this method?

Is this maybe the case, because the data is somehow buffered, and android is calling the callback immidiately when its setting the result callback ?

Answer (score 1):

You have forceReload set to false in the Games.Achievements.load() request so it's going to use data caching most of the time. I'm not sure if the method will then immediately run the callback on the same thread, but it sounds like it is.

If you don't like the way it's working you can always run getAchievemnts() on your own separate thread, and then use await() to bypass the callback.

Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult result=load.await();